# Inner Join en consulta mysql en php

Tags: php, mysql

queria pedirles ayuda con esta consulta, la aplicacion si guarda los datos en la base de datos, pero no muestra los registros en la app, queda cargando

```
public function listar()
    {
        $sql="SELECT a.idpelicula, a.idgenero,a.idformato,a.idclasificacion, c.nombre as genero, c.nombre as formato, c.nombre as clasificacion, a.codigo, a.nombre, a.stock,a.duracion ,a.idioma,a.descripcion, a.imagen, a.condicion from pelicula as a 
        inner join genero as c 
          on a.idgenero=c.idgenero 
        
        inner join formato as c 
        on a.idformato=c.idformato 

        inner join clasificacion as c
        on a.idclasificacion=c.idclasificacion";
        return ejecutarConsulta($sql);

    
    }
```

me podrian ayudar, creo yo que esa consulta es la que hace que no se vean, en que esta mal? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa los alias `as`, le pusiste el mismo alias `c` a todos

Comment: en esa tabla, la principal id es idpelicula, idgenero,formato y clasificacion son llaves foraneas codigo, nombre, stock etc son de pelicula

Comment: tienes toda la razon bro, ya quedo, muchas gracias, al final quedo inner join clasificacion as g inner join formato as f inner join genero as c gracias bendiciones

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo tu consulta realiza inner join a trablas que podrían estar en otras DB
realiza esto de ejemplo

```
INNER JOIN nombre_db.genero C ON A.idgenero = C.idgenero
```

sugerencia reliza la consulta en una query para tu db, cuando te funcione la usas en tu PHP, te dara mas posibilidades a depurar.

Comment: si bro, muchas gracias, ya quedo resuelto